# AngularJS data-binding between two arrays

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have table and a select control:

```
<table>
<tr ng-repeat="object in objects" ng-click="setCurrentSelectObject(object)">
<td>{{object.id}}</td>
<td>{{object.member_id}}</td>
<td>{{object.description}}</td>
</tr>
</table>

<select ng-options="m for m in members" ></select>
```

`members` and `objects` are some arrays that are loaded using `$resource` by AngularJS.
`object.member_id` is a *foreign key* value to `members.id`  , I want to bind `object.member_id` with the selected `member.id` in the select control.

How do I do that ?

**Edit:**
My approach until now:

I use `ng-model=selectedMember` inside the `select` control, and that gives me a member array, which is a complex structure from which I only need `member.id` and `on-change="changedMember"`.
Inside `changeMember` I have the current selected object from the table to which I do : `currentObject.member_id = selectedMember`.

But this is a workaround, isn 't there a more ***ng-model***-ish way of doing this ?

Comment: use `ng-model` on select and bind to something like `selectedMember` in scope

Comment: I have described my current approach in the edited post, but I am not satisfied with it.

Comment: "current selected object from the table" - how do you select something from the table? Are you trying to set the `object.member_id` for all `members` based on the `<select>` changing? What you describe you want is confusing

Comment: Well that is what I was trying to avoid. I only want to set the object.member_id of only one 'object' object based on the <select>

Comment: the 'setCurrentSelectObject' method gets me the current selected object, sorry for being ambiguous

Comment: Is this something like what you have? http://jsfiddle.net/Za5Ge/ - and you don't want to have to handle the `ng-change` of the `<select>`, but achieve the same thing?

Comment: Exactly, you are very correct.